# dd element extending passed parent element width

Tags: css

Here is my HTML which is outputting data from the database:

```
<div class="desc">
    <dl>
        <dt><?php echo $listing['name'] ?> <span class="distance">(3.4 miles)</span></dt>
        <dd><?php echo $listing['address'] ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $listing['city'].', '.$listing['state'].' '.$listing['zip'] ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $listing['phone'] ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $listing['email'] ?></dd>
    </dl>
    <p><a href="#">See on map</a> | <a href="<?php echo $listing['web_link'] ?>" target="_blank">Go to Website</a></p>
</div>
```

Then my CSS:

```
dt { font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; }
dd { margin-left: 0; }
dl { margin: 0; }
div.desc {
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 0 12px;
}
```

And a jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Xk58n/2/

However, the dd is extending passed the width of the .desc container when I view it in Chrome.

Comment: Providing a fiddle with your question is a good idea, but it's important that it actually demonstrate your problem. If I quickly fill in some dummy values where you have PHP values, your example seems to be working just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/nate/KqTxW/3/

Comment: I fiddled your code and see no difference from google to firefox.

Comment: @Nate I just did the same, see OP second jsFiddle link.

Comment: Updated my main post with JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Xk58n/1/

Comment: Wait for some odd reason it's not showing the correct jsfiddle I came up with.

Comment: Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/Xk58n/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `word-break:break-word;` rule to your `#listings dl` CSS:

```
#listings dl {
    margin: 0;
    word-break:break-word;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Xk58n/3/)**